# calculating in a core data entity via a table view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

As a complete Coca beginner I need help to do a calculation on a core data entity.
Let's assume the entity has 3 attributes, a, b, and c.

Where c = a * b

When I change the entry for a in the table view with the columns a, b and c I want c to be recalculated.

So far I have sub-classed an array controller myArrayController from NSArrayController and set it as the custom class in the identity inspector.

In QT I could have worked with a signal emitted by the table view in case a cell is changed. How would I do it in Cocoa?
If I control-drag a button and create an action, it is obviously triggered when the button is clicked.
But with a Text Field Cell...? 
How do I calculate c when the value in column a has been changed?
(my first idea would be to ctrl-drag an action into the array controller; but to be honest I have not understood the mechanics well enough and could not find a suitable example in books to judge if I am heading in the wrong direction)

Comment: Have you any question about my answer?

Comment: Look at updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Jack Nutting and Peter Clark's "Learn Cocoa on the Mac" chapter 8, page 186 I found the following solution:

I removed attribute c from the cocoa model and created a managedObject subclass.
In this suclass I had to implement 2 additional methods:

```
- (double) c
{
    double c = [[self valueForKey:@"a"] doubleValue] *[[self valueForKey:@"b"] doubleValue]] ;

    return c;
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingC {

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"a", @"b", nil];
}
```

Then bind the "text field cell - table view cell" to "Table Cell View" (and not the array controller, as described in the book).

And you should be good to go. :-)

I tried it out and could verify that it worked.
But thanks to Oleg I got on the right track and I am sure his solution also has its benefits.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

At first:

override accessor method in entity class

```
@implementation Entity

@dynamic a;
@dynamic b;
@dynamic c;

-(NSNumber*) c
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.a floatValue]*[self.b integerValue]];
}

-(void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"needSave" object:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"needUpdate" object:self];
    [super didChangeValueForKey:key];
}

@end
```

In your controller you should add this in didLoad method or applicationDidFinishLaunching if it is a appDelegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateTables)
                                             name:@"needUpdate"
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(save)
                                             name:@"needSave"
                                           object:nil];

-(void)updateTables
{
    [table reloadData];
}

-(void)save
{
    NSError *err = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&err];
}
```

So, when array controller will access to `c` property, she will recalculated. But don't forget set `Transient` property for `c` property in **attribute inspector** of xcdatamodel.

[image]

And you should never use `setC:` method.

Second:

You don't should write subclass of NSArrayController for working with custom entities.

Comment: thanks for the hint! I gather I need to create a class from the entity. I found instructions that this can be done straight from the modeller. The book is German so I will not copy the text here. But if you click "editor" there is "create NSManagedObject Subclass" thanks... I keep trying

Comment: Press cmd+n, then choose "core data" item, then managedObject subclass @RogerWilco77

Comment: If you got solution of your problem you can accept my answer. If you need anything else just tell. @RogerWilco77

Comment: Hi, the update works only if i write something new in column c but not when I change a or b.

Comment: Hi. I have my own app where i use code like in my post and he's works well. Tell me more, what you actually doing? How you connect entity to the array controller, how you connect tableview rows to the controller, do you use nsformatter in cells of rows in table view, which connected to entities a,b,c? @RogerWilco77

Comment: thanks for your patience. I could not come back sooner... the actual table has 8 columns and is related to a core data object with 8 properties.The binding was done from the "text field cell" to "objectValueValue.PROPERTY" for each column. Yes, some have a NSNUmberFormatter. Oh the Table View the table content is bound to the array controller with the key "arrangedObjects". Selection indexes to the same array with controller key "selectionIndexes". The array controller was dragged into the designer. Managed Object Context is bound o "File's Owner".

Comment: Look at code, which i add to my answer. After your entity was changed, she must post notification about that. your controller should save context, after that he should update table. I think there is more ways for do that, but this way well work for me. @RogerWilco77